# Acquiring the global interpreter lock from python

Tags: python, multithreading, gil

Is it possible to acquire the global interpreter lock from python code? Or is that purely implemented in the C side?

Comment: Don't you dare touch the GIL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your code executes then you have the GIL, no need to acquire it manually.

Comment: Right; there is no need to ever mess with the GIL.

Comment: There are times when you need to do transactions (multiple commands without thread-switching). How can I guarantee this if not without explicit acquisition of the GIL?

Comment: If you can not do this with locks/semaphores or other things from the `threading` module you are probably doing something wrong.